# How to calculate the diameter of the TouchPoint on an iPhone,iPad and Android Device?

Tags: iphone, touch, multi-touch, gesture-recognition

Now i understand we can have 5 touch points by default in iPhone and have varied touch points enabled onto the different SDKs. However i have accomplished registering the touch points and getting distances, actual number of touch points. I would want to know if there's a way to accomplish and get the Diameter of a particular touch point for e.g. calculating the thumb touch in comparison with the index finger, Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible, at least on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

I think Apple makes it fairly clear that they don't intend to give third-party developers access to low-level multi-touch information. From Apple's documentation on [Event Handling in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html):

> A finger on the screen affords a much different level of precision
>   than a mouse pointer. When a user touches the screen, the area of
>   contact is actually elliptical and tends to be offset below the point
>   where the user thinks he or she touched. This “contact patch” also
>   varies in size and shape based on which finger is touching the screen,
>   the size of the finger, the pressure of the finger on the screen, the
>   orientation of the finger, and other factors. The underlying
>   Multi-Touch system analyzes all of this information for you and
>   computes a single touch point.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and i have already read that. However i still feel that there might be a workaround for the same, do you think there is?

Comment: I am not aware of any public class that provides this information. Without access to lower-level APIs, it simply isn't possible to extract that information - and those lower-level APIs are likely to remain private indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t speak to Android, but the public APIs in the iOS SDK don’t give you any information about a touch other than its position. [These guys](http://tenonedesign.com/blog/pressure-sensitive-drawing-on-ipad/) found a private API (i.e. one that’ll get you rejected from the App Store if you use it) for getting the diameter of a touch on the screen, but they haven’t provided any further information or released the library.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely possible on Android (4.3 I have, but most likely others too), as you can both activate an overlay display of touch properties in the *Developer options*  as *Pointer location* (in *Input* category), which shows you coordinates, their Delta (=difference) and two properties you might be interested in: *Prs*, that is **pressure** and ***Size***. It seems you can find the thresholds that would recognize a thumb and the index finger in most cases. That's just what I would imply from the values I have seen in that display.

A proof that this is possible within the allowed API is [*Yet Another MultiTouch Test*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rn.yamtt&hl=en) Android App listed on on Google Play which for me shows the pressure of each touch in it's own interface (so it must be available in the standard API).