# How get touchs size

Tags: ios, ipad

In android is possible get size and pressure of a touch. In iOS I know that isn't possible get pressure. But, at least the touch size, some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search a little more and I conclude:
There is no support for that according to this another [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097150/how-to-calculate-the-diameter-of-the-touchpoint-on-an-iphone-ipad-and-android-dev)

I little more and even private API couldn't help. What make me believe the touchscreen controller doesn't send the low-level detailed touch, but direct the calculated point. Who knows?!

Now I should rethink about my app interaction. I hope it helps others in the same problem.