# UITouch major radius not changed smoothly

Tags: ios, uitouch

I've got a problem with majorRadius property on UITouch.

I'm implementing drawing app and wanted to add some kind of "pressure" drawing.

So for this i use getting size of a touch. But the values of majorRadius property doesn't change smoothly - they changed by some number, but it is not good for me.

Someone can help me how i can get change more smoothly or get proof that is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITouch/majorRadius) this is an approximate value:

> Use the value in this property to determine the size of the touch that
>   was reported by the hardware. **This value is an approximation of the
>   size** and **can vary by the amount specified in the *majorRadiusTolerance*
>   property**.

If you need pressure detection here you can find help: [Tap pressure strength detection using accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179426/tap-pressure-strength-detection-using-accelerometer)

Comment: i tried this approach but seems it can be used only for single touches, but can't be used for moved touches. For hard touches it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it, it went up in increments of `2 * majorRadiusTolerance`.

This is iOS8. In iOS7 the API was not public yet, but you [could get the radius parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864622/how-to-get-touch-size-in-ios) from the OS by accessing

```
@interface UITouch (Private)
-(float)_pathMajorRadius;
@end
```

This would indeed change smoothly with pressure area. Be aware that using this interface would get you banned from the AppStore, though.

For your drawing app I recommend to spline the majorRadius values and extract interpolated values from the spline.

Comment: in ios 7 we use pathMajorRadius for drawing with touch sizes and it works good. But on ios 8 it works like majorRadius.

Comment: @ВячеславОкулов: So there you have your proof that it is expected behavior.